# problema con WordPress y https

Tags: wordpress, https, ssl

hoy he puesto un certificado ssl en mi wordpress en la pagina del home todo perfecto pero en todas las demás me da error 404 al entrar en https, si entro con http las paginas si que funcionan.

Comment: verificastes si por apache puedes entrar por el puerto 443?

Comment: Y en Ajustes > Generales tienes dos variables, Dirección de WordPress y Dirección del Sitio, verifica qué contienen esas variables.

Comment: gracias, si eso esta en https, lo raro es que el home va bien con https i las demas paginas no

Comment: esto pone en el servidor creo que quiere decir que si                                          `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: he encontrado una solución temporal cambiando los links permanentes puedo acceder a las paginas

Answer (score 0):

Esto sucede porque has cambiado el dominio de tu página pero las entradas siguen apuntando al antiguo dominio (http -> https se considera cambio de dominio).

Para solventar este problema tienes dos soluciones (entre tantas):

**Actualizar el archivo .htaccess**

Accede a Ajustes > Personalización > Enlaces permanentes y le das a guardar (esto actualiza tu .htaccess, en teoria se 'da cuenta' de que el domino ha sido modificado y actualiza los enlaces.

**Actualizar los enlaces de las entradas/paginas:**

*Ojo, antes de realizar el siguiente paso es extremadamente recomendable realizar un backup:*

Accedes a tu base de datos y ejecutas la siguiente consulta:

```
UPDATE wp_post
SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'http://', 'https://')
```

Ten encuenta que 'wp'_post puede ser 'cualquiercosa'_post, tienes que fijarte en el nombre exacto de tu base de datos.

Comment: como modifico entra por entrada? porque desde la edicion de la misma entrada solo permite modificar la ultima parte del link

Comment: Error mío, actualizado.

Comment: muchas gracias @Hamza aun que no he conseguido que funcione muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre he utilizado este plugin y nunca he tenido problemas:

[Easy HTTPS Redirection (SSL)](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/https-redirection/)

Solo es instalarlo y activarlo.

Acciones: Hacer una redirección automática para todo el dominio. En este caso cada URL será redirigida a la versión HTTPS automáticamente.
Acciones: Hacer una redirección automática para algunas páginas. El usuario puede ingresar las URL que se redirigirán automáticamente a la versión de HTTPS.
Forzar la carga de archivos estáticos (imágenes, js, css, etc…) usando una URL HTTPS.

Éxitos!